# Sequelize: Concat fields in WHERE LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using the sequelize ORM for a node.js project I am working on. One query I have, I need to perform a like operation on the concatenated result of multiple columns.

For instance, something like the following:

SELECT * FROM People WHERE (CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) LIKE '%John Do%'.

I am using the following syntax and would like to know if this is possible without having to resort to using RAW queries (which is nowhere else in my solution).

```
   var criteria = {
        include: [
            occupation
        ],
        where: {
            is_active: 1
        },
        nest: false
    };

    db.people.findAll(criteria, {}).then(function(people) {
        success(people);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        error(err);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You'll need something like this

```
var criteria = {
    where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn("concat", Sequelize.col("firstname"), Sequelize.col("lastname")), {
        like: '%John Do%'
    })
}
```

Note: *untested*

[Original source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2077#issuecomment-58616291)

Answer (score 24):

Inspired by @code-jaff but you need to concatenate a space string in between first and last names to make this work correctly. Otherwise it would only return for 'JohnDoe' and not for 'John Doe'. Here's the code.

```
  Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), {
    like: '% John Doe %'
  })
```

To provide some context for people who might not understand where this would fit into your query, this is an example of the above code in a where or statement. req.body.query being the variable search term that you're POSTing.

```
Users.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
      Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), {
        like: '%' + req.body.query + '%'
      }),
        { email: { $like: '%' + req.body.query + '%' } },
        { companyName: { $like: '%' + req.body.query + '%' } }
    ]
  }
})
```

*Update for Sequelize 4.0*

String based operators (`$like` and `$or` in the above example) have been deprecated in favour of symbol based operators. It's a good thing for security

See: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators

These operators would be replaced with `[Sequelize.Op.like]` and `[Sequelize.Op.or]`. There are also other ways to configure it in your sequelize options highlighted in their documentation

Comment: I had to replace the `like` inside `Sequelize.where` with `[Sequelize.Op.like]` to get it work.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to achieve this with the new sequelize version 5.21.13 based on @yjimk answer.

```
Users.findAll({
  where: {
    [sequelize.Op.or]:{
     namesQuery: sequelize.where(
      sequelize.fn(
        "concat",
        sequelize.col("firstName"),
        " ",
        sequelize.col("lastName")
      ),
      {
        [sequelize.Op.like]: `%${req.body.query}%`,
      }
    ),
    email: {[sequelize.Op.like]: `%${req.body.query}%`},
    companyName: {[sequelize.Op.like]: `%${req.body.query}%`},
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.models.users.findOne({ 
            where: {
                [db.sequelize.Op.and]: [
                    db.sequelize.where(
                        db.sequelize.fn('CONCAT', db.sequelize.col('first_name'), ' ', db.sequelize.col('last_name')), 
                        { like: `%${name}%` },
                    ),
                    { status: 'ACTIVE' },
                ]
            }
        });
```