# How to concat two columns for search with feathers-sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I need to search for users by name, their first name and last names are stored in separate columns in a postgresql database. The columns need to be concatenated for search to work properly. Typing the full first and last name of a user should match a result.

What could I pass as a query to the find method of a Feathers service that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Here's how to do columns concatenation in where clause
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752840/sequelize-concat-fields-in-where-like-clause#answer-32759361

Comment: This is more of a feathers-sequelize specific question

Answer (score 3):

As in the [answer linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752840/sequelize-concat-fields-in-where-like-clause#answer-32759361) you can pass the `where` clause to the Feathers service by modifying `params.query` in a [before hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/hooks/usage.html#before-hooks):

```
app.service('users').before({
  find(hook) {
    const where = Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn("concat",
      Sequelize.col("firstname"),
      Sequelize.col("lastname")), {
        like: '%John Do%'
      }
    );

    hook.params.query.where = where;
  }
})
```