# How can I concat a relation in a Sequelize 'where'?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

How can I combine two string columns from a **relation** in a where query?
I have a table Car with a relation to the table Owner.

I tried the below, but it fails with the error

> SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "carOwner"

```
  const result = Car.findAll({
    where: sequelize.where(
      sequelize.fn(
        'concat',
        sequelize.col('carOwner.firstName'),
        ' ',
        sequelize.col('carOwner.lastName'),
      ),
      {
        [op.iLike]: `%${query}%`,
      },
    ),
  })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize: Concat fields in WHERE LIKE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752840/sequelize-concat-fields-in-where-like-clause)

Comment: @fubar I already checked that one, it doesn't use relations

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what doesn't work? What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to include the associated model `CarOwner` :

```
Car.findAll({
    where: sequelize.where(
        sequelize.fn(
            'concat',
            sequelize.col('carOwner.firstName'),
            ' ',
            sequelize.col('carOwner.lastName'),
        ), {
            [op.iLike]: `%${query}%`,
        },
    ),
    include : {
        model : CarOwner , // <---- HERE
        required : true
    }
})
```

Comment: Instead of columns, how to concat attributes in jsonb?