# how can concat columns in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize and node.js. I want to concat the value of columns of PrimaryPractice's model to each other.
How can I solve this problem?
this is my codes:

```
ProviderPayer.findAll({
                  where: {
                      orgPayerId: {
                          [Op.in]: orgPayerIds
                      }
                  },
                  attributes: ["effective_date"],
                  include: [{
                          model: PayerTracks,
                          attributes: ["title"],
                          as: "payers",
                      },
                      {
                          model: User,
                          where: {
                              id: {[Op.in]: userIds},
                              deletedAt: null,
                              status: {[Op.ne]: STATUS.INACTIVE}
                          },
                          attributes: ["id"],
                          include: [
                              {
                                  model: PrimaryPractice,
                                  as: "primaryPractice",
                                  attributes: [
                                   "addressStreetPrimPract", 
                                   "addressStreet2PrimPract", 
                                   "addressCityPrimPract", 
                                   "addressStatePrimPract", 
                                   "addressZipPrimPract"]
                              }
                          ]
                      }

                  ]
              })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your DBMS has something like `CONCAT` function then you can try something like this:

```js
attributes: [
  [
    sequelize.fn('CONCAT',
      sequelize.col('addressStreetPrimPract'), ', ', 
      sequelize.col('addressStreet2PrimPract'), ', ', 
      sequelize.col('addressCityPrimPract'), ', ', 
      sequelize.col('addressStatePrimPract'), ', ', 
      sequelize.col('addressZipPrimPract')
    ),
    'concatenated_fields_alias'
  ],
],
```

Comment: I removed old attributes leaviing CONCAT only

Answer (score 1):

```
attributes: [sequelize.fn('CONCAT',
    sequelize.col('addressStreetPrimPract'), ' ',
    sequelize.col('addressStreet2PrimPract'), ' ',
    sequelize.col('addressCityPrimPract'), ' ',
    sequelize.col('addressStatePrimPract'), ' ',
    sequelize.col('addressZipPrimPract')
),
'name_of_concatenated_fields'
]
```

you can see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819641/12761193) also for reference

Comment: I run this code but return this error message : "Tried to select attributes using Sequelize.cast or Sequelize.fn without specifying an alias for the result, during eager loading. This means the attribute will not be added to the returned instance"

Comment: I forgot to use sequelize before fn now try

Comment: that is true ,either  we must put  another [ ]