# Sequelize – querying with two attributes?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a search box where the user can enter his query e.g. `John Doe`.

I also have `User` model defined, with columns `first_name` and `last_name`. The model has also a `full_name` virtual column set.

I want to search for user's full name and I tried this:

```
const search = 'John Doe';
await DB.User.findAll({
  where: {
    [Sequelize.Op.or]: {
      first_name: { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` },
      last_name: { [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%` },
    },
  },
});
```

Having only `John` or only `Doe` works, but if someone writes a full name – nope – and this is understandable.

I've tried querying `full_name`, but it says the column does not exist.

**My question – how should I perform a query like this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819641/12995272) you should be able to use

```
const search = 'John Doe';
await DB.User.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('first_name'), ' ', Sequelize.col('last_name')), {
    [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`
  })
});
```